# How to convert json formatting from Object to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Another issue :P, I'm trying to change the output of the JSON array but I can't workout why it won't render the other files.

Edit better explanation below.

Sorry i was not very clear if you look at the code in my gist,       data[name] = { will render all the return names into there individual json files, But if i remove the [name] and its just data = { the individual files are not rendered and the all.json file is made from the rendered [name] files.
Hope this explains it a little better.
The code you gave me dose add "markets" [] to the all.json file as it should but without the other files all.json only has one return.
The reason why i want to remove [name] from the data[name] = is that it adds the name to the start of the string of every return eg { "Bitcoin": {"position": "1", "name":"Bitcoin",},{"Litecoin": {"position":"2", "name": "Litecoin", }, and so on.

So i guess what i am trying to do is move the [name] from the data[name] =
into the fs.writeFile function and only add "markets": at the start of the string and still be able to render the individual files into all.json.

The Node.js code that will not render the individual files.

This versions all.json only returns

```
{"position":"650","name":"Pennies","symbol":"CENT","icon":"pennies.png","market_cap":{"usd":"NaN","btc":"?"},"price":{"usd":"2.26018e-9","btc":"9.05947e-12"},"supply":"","volume":{"usd":"43.9142","btc":"0.176021"},"change1h":"0.05","change24h":"3.77","change1d":"-7.07","timestamp":1435559515.397}
```

and in the json folder

http://s21.postimg.org/xm7v01ujr/image.jpg

What I would like is the JSON format to be:

```
{
    "markets": [
        {
            "position": "1",
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "icon": "bitcoin.png",
            "market_cap": {
                "usd": "3504403422",
                "btc": "14319000.0"
            },
            "price": {
                "usd": "244.738",
                "btc": "1.0"
            },
            "supply": "14319000",
            "volume": {
                "usd": "13563600",
                "btc": "55523.8"
            },
            "change1h": "0.26",
            "change24h": "1.05",
            "change1d": "1.21",
            "timestamp": 1435401749.236
        },
        {
            "position": "2",
            "name": "Litecoin",
            and so on.......
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    fs = require("fs");
 
var currencies = ["usd", "btc"];
var currencyExchangeRates = Array();
var data = {};
 
request('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    currencyExchangeRates = $("#currency-exchange-rates").data();
    $("tr").each(function (i) {
     if (i > 0) {
 var td = $(this).find("td");
        var position = td.eq(0).text().trim();
        var icon = $(this).find("img.currency-logo").attr("src").replace("/static/img/coins/16x16/", "");
 var name = td.eq(1).text().replace("/", "").trim();
        var re = /\s([a-z]|[0-9])+\s/i;
        var supplyText = td.eq(5).text();
        var symbol = td.eq(2).text().trim();
 var marketCap = currencyDictionary(td.eq(3));
        var price = currencyDictionary(td.eq(4).find("a").eq(0));
 var supply = td.eq(5).text().replace(/\D/g, "").trim(); // Replace all non digit characters with nothing
 var volume = currencyDictionary(td.eq(6).find("a").eq(0));
 var change1h = td.eq(7).text().replace("%", "").trim();
        var change24h = td.eq(8).text().replace("%", "").trim();
        var change1d = td.eq(9).text().replace("%", "").trim();
 var timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
 data = [{
            "position": position,
            "name": name,
            "symbol": symbol,
            "icon": icon,
            "market_cap": marketCap,
            "price": price,
            "supply": supply,
            "volume": volume,
            "change1h": change1h,
            "change24h": change24h,
            "change1d": change1d,
            "timestamp": timestamp
        }];
      }
    });
    writeData();
  }
});
 
function currencyDictionary(item) {
  var resultArray = {};
  currencies.forEach(function(currency) {
    if (currency == "btc") {
      var result = item.data("btc");
    }
    else {
      var result = item.data("usd") / currencyExchangeRates[currency];
    }
    resultArray[currency] = result.toString().replace(/,/g,"");
  });
  return resultArray;
}
 
function writeData() {
    dataDir = "/var/www/coinmarketcap/json/";
    callback = function(error) {
 if (error) {
     console.log(error);
 }
    };
    for (currency in data) {
    info = data[currency];
    fileName = dataDir + info["symbol"] + ".json";
    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(info), callback);
    }
    fs.writeFile(dataDir + "all.json", JSON.stringify(data), callback);
}
```

This version will render all the files but adds the [name] to the all.json

this version json folder

http://s16.postimg.org/xicupqi85/image.jpg

The JSON format is:

```
{
    "Bitcoin":
  {
    "position": "1",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "icon": "bitcoin.png",
    "market_cap": {
      "usd": "3504403422",
      "btc": "14319000.0"
    },
    "price": {
      "usd": "244.738",
      "btc": "1.0"
    },
    "supply": "14319000",
    "volume": {
      "usd": "13563600",
      "btc": "55523.8"
    },
    "change1h": "0.26",
    "change24h": "1.05",
    "change1d": "1.21",
    "timestamp": 1435401749.236
  },
{ 
    "Litecoin": 
  { 
    "position" "2",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    and so on...
  }
}
```

```js
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    fs = require("fs");
 
var currencies = ["usd", "btc"];
var currencyExchangeRates = Array();
var data = {};
 
request('http://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    currencyExchangeRates = $("#currency-exchange-rates").data();
    $("tr").each(function (i) {
     if (i > 0) {
 var td = $(this).find("td");
        var position = td.eq(0).text().trim();
        var icon = $(this).find("img.currency-logo").attr("src").replace("/static/img/coins/16x16/", "");
 var name = td.eq(1).text().replace("/", "").trim();
        var re = /\s([a-z]|[0-9])+\s/i;
        var supplyText = td.eq(5).text();
        var symbol = td.eq(2).text().trim();
 var marketCap = currencyDictionary(td.eq(3));
        var price = currencyDictionary(td.eq(4).find("a").eq(0));
 var supply = td.eq(5).text().replace(/\D/g, "").trim(); // Replace all non digit characters with nothing
 var volume = currencyDictionary(td.eq(6).find("a").eq(0));
 var change1h = td.eq(7).text().replace("%", "").trim();
        var change24h = td.eq(8).text().replace("%", "").trim();
        var change1d = td.eq(9).text().replace("%", "").trim();
 var timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
 data[name] = {
            "position": position,
            "name": name,
            "symbol": symbol,
            "icon": icon,
            "market_cap": marketCap,
            "price": price,
            "supply": supply,
            "volume": volume,
            "change1h": change1h,
            "change24h": change24h,
            "change1d": change1d,
            "timestamp": timestamp
        };
      }
    });
    writeData();
  }
});
 
function currencyDictionary(item) {
  var resultArray = {};
  currencies.forEach(function(currency) {
    if (currency == "btc") {
      var result = item.data("btc");
    }
    else {
      var result = item.data("usd") / currencyExchangeRates[currency];
    }
    resultArray[currency] = result.toString().replace(/,/g,"");
  });
  return resultArray;
}
 
function writeData() {
    dataDir = "/var/www/coinmarketcap/json/";
    callback = function(error) {
 if (error) {
     console.log(error);
 }
    };
    for (currency in data) {
    info = data[currency];
    fileName = dataDir + info["symbol"] + ".json";
    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(info), callback);
    }
    fs.writeFile(dataDir + "all.json", JSON.stringify(data), callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `for...in` loop

```js
var data = {
    "Bitcoin":
  {
    "position": "1",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "icon": "bitcoin.png",
    "market_cap": {
      "usd": "3504403422",
      "btc": "14319000.0"
    },
    "price": {
      "usd": "244.738",
      "btc": "1.0"
    },
    "supply": "14319000",
    "volume": {
      "usd": "13563600",
      "btc": "55523.8"
    },
    "change1h": "0.26",
    "change24h": "1.05",
    "change1d": "1.21",
    "timestamp": 1435401749.236
  }
};

var res = {"markets":[]};

for (var prop in data) {
  res.markets.push(data[prop])
};

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean can you add it to a gist with the edits to the code on my gist.

Comment: @NRPatten _"Not sure what you mean"_ . At OP requirement appear to be: _"The JSON format is now like:"_ -> _"would like is:"_  ?

Comment: Sorry better explanation above

Comment: @NRPatten Still not certain about requirement ? Question at original post appear to be _"The JSON format is now like:"_ -> _"would like is:"_ ?Perhaps include all portions of `js` , `json` at Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NRPatten Still not certain about exact requirement ? `js` at post attempts solution for original post at _"The JSON format is now like:" -> "would like is:"_

Comment: i think that explains it a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, had to move the fs.writeFile for all.json out of the writeData function and give all.json its own function that is called after the writeData function had finished.